# querying a self referencing table in Django

Tags: sql, django

I have a model which references itself so that I have a parent / child relationship between users in the db. A parent can have multiple children, but a child can only have one parent.

Firstly, is this the correct way to define the model:

```
class User(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   parent = models.ForeignKey('self')
```

Secondly, I need to query the model and return all the children of a particular parent. I have read some articles on tree structures where queries can be more complicated. But given I only need one layer deep, will this return **all** the children:

```
children = User.objects.get(parent=PARENT_ID)
```

where PARENT_ID is obviously the id of the parent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use like your code.

and Yes again, but little bit different.

```
children = User.objects.filter(parent__id=PARENT_ID)
```

You can find children with `parent__id`

> Note; remember parent _ _ id , not parent_id!

Comment: Is it possible to search for the parent by passing the parent object? I.e., say we had "p" as a user object, then doing children=User.objects.get(parent=p) ?

Comment: So you want to search parent's parent?

Comment: Oh, sure. children=User.objects.filter(parent=p)  is basic!

Comment: NOTE; not `get` but `filter`